# There is a problem with my component I wanted to know what's wrong

Tags: reactjs

I've got a problem with the "hello world" component I made.

```
'Message' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type '() => void' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) =>           ReactNode'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

that's it.

the component:

```
 function Message(){
        <h1>hello world</h1>;
    }

    export default Message;
```

the App:

```
    import Message from "./message"

    function App(){
      return <div><Message /></div>

    }

    export default App
```

Comment: Typo?  You forgot to *return* anything from `Message`.

Comment: Please also take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the section title "Write a title that summarizes the problem"

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the JSX value:

```
function Message() {
  return <h1>hello world</h1>;
}
```

The error message `Its type '() => void' is not a valid JSX element type.` tells you that the function is returning nothing (void).